# mySQL "select" is case sensitive through JDBC but not through command line

Tags: mysql, jdbc, applet, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am trying to search my database using mySQL through JDBC.  When I use this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name='joe';
```

It does a case insensitive search and returns any rows that have 'Joe' or 'joe', which is what I want.  I ran `select collation(version())`, and this returned 'utf8_general_ci', which is apparently supposed to be case insensitive.  However, when I run the same query using JDBC within my Java applet, it does a case sensitive search.  Here is my `query2` function:

```
try {
        Vector<Vector<String>> out = new Vector<Vector<String>>() ;
        Connection con = connect() ;
        Statement statement = con.createStatement() ;
        System.out.println( "SQL: " + s ) ;
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(s) ;
        while( rs.next() )
        {
            String r = rs.getString(1) ; // RS is indexed from 1
            Vector<String> q = new Vector<String>() ;
            for( int i = 2 ; i <= tableSize ; i ++ )
            {
                q.add(r) ;
                r = rs.getString(i) ;
            }
            q.add(r) ;
            out.add(q) ;
        }
        con.close() ;
        return( out ) ;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println( "SQL EXCEPTION" ) ;
        System.err.println( s ) ;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is my `select` function that calls `query2`:

```
public static Vector<Vector<String>> select( String table , List<String> columns , List<String> values )
{
    String statement = "SELECT * from `" + table + "` WHERE " ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < columns.size(); i ++ )
    {
        statement += columns.get(i) + "='" + values.get(i) + "'" ;
        if( i + 1 < columns.size() )
            statement += " AND " ;
    }
    statement += " ;" ;
    return query2 ( statement , tableSize(table) ) ;
}
```

Any idea how I can make this query case insensitive?

Comment: You could just do: `WHERE LOWER(name) = 'joe'`

Comment: Also, it relies on the OS under mysql. Check docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the search I thought was using the `select` function was actually using a different function.  This function was selecting everything from the database and sorting through it client-side.  I tested the `select` function and it actually is case insensitive, without having to use any of the tips given (but thanks for the advice!).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this line need to read

```
statement += "UPPER("+columns.get(i) + ")='UPPER(" + values.get(i) + ")'"
```

downfall... can't use indexes since it's uppering everything.